# can't insert apostrophe inside textarea and insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, sql-injection

When i am trying to insert some text with apostrophe inside textare to mysql database it simply just wont insert anything, anyone know why this is ?
I hope that someone can help me.

some code

PHP

```
foreach ($_POST['episode'] as $episode => $value ) {
            $episode_title = $value['episode_title'];
            $episode_filename = $value['episode_filename'];
            $episode_image = $value['episode_image'];
            $episode_description = $value['episode_description'];
            $subtitle_language = $value['subtitle_language'];
            $subtitle_filename = $value['subtitle_filename'];
            $image_extension = $value['image_extension'];
            $sql_episode = "INSERT INTO episodes VALUES ('', '$episode_title', '$episode_filename', '$episode_image', '$episode_description', '$subtitle_language', '$subtitle_filename', '$image_extension', '$inserted_child_id', '$inserted_cover_id')";
            if ($db->query($sql_episode) === TRUE) {
                $inserted_episode_id = $db->insert_id;
            }

        }
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="episode[0][episode_description]" placeholder="Episode Description..."></textarea>
```

Comment: you would need to either escape your variables or use prepared statements.  note: showing some of your code will help people assist you

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Not related to your issue, but [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) may be able to save you a bit of effort if you're just assigning variables based  on name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 'escape' your strings, so that quotes do not break the code structure.  Pass your posted variable through one or more of:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$string);
addslashes($string);
```

or other similar functions, to convert or 'escape' quotes.

eg:

```
$episode_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$value['episode_description']);
```

Comment: No, neither “one or more of” nor `addslashes` in particular.